# Is it okay to not include "À l’attention de" in a "lettre de motivation"?

Tags: professionalism, cover-letter, france

I'm required to write a French "lettre de motivation" for an internship in a French school.

I don't know the name of the director of the school or HR manager or their gender, bearing in mind that I will submit it in person.

Is it okay to not include the phrase "À l’attention de ..." in the right?

I found many such examples in the following source but I'm not convinced.

Here is an example of how the top of the document will be:

[image]

Source: 100 CV et lettres de motivation pour tous les profils by Dominique Perez

Thank you

Comment: Do you at least know the title of the person to whom it should be addressed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Please don't judge based on the Anglo and Franco culture. This is related to an ex-colony of France.

Comment: Oh I'm not judging I was just hoping to suggest using the title or director of the office for attention

Comment: A quick Internet search or phone call to their main office would probably get you the name or title of the person you should be writing to. Part of job hunting is learning to get this type of information.

Answer (score 2):

In a formal letter, you do need some sort of header, and you can't just write "Hiring Manager" on it, as it comes off as coarse and unrefined. It doesn't necessarily have to be "To the attention of," but something does need to be there.

I'm assuming here that "À l’attention de" means "To the attention of", which is a valid header to use.

In english at least, we might also use the phrase "Dear Hiring Manager" or "Dear HR Manager" if you don't know the person's name and haven't met them before.

Comment: Depends how formal written French is the English strictly formal salutation in this case is "Dear Sirs" or Sir Or Madame